# Excel: How to count # of occurrences

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of Part #s and the programs that they are used in. Looks like this:

```
Part #s.     Programs.    Results

A            A             3
A            B
A            C
B            A             1
C            A             1
D            A             1
```

How do I go about getting the results to show how many programs use the one part?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this Formula?

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,A1,B:B,B1)
```

*Image For the result* **OUTPUT**

[Count Variables](https://exceljet.net/sites/default/files/styles/function_screen/public/images/formulas/count%20items%20in%20list.png?itok=hv8beO3W)

**References:**

[Count Items In a List](https://exceljet.net/formula/count-items-in-list)

*Hope This helps*

*My Sincerely,*

**Xavier**

Answer (score 0):

The data shown raises more questions for me than it answers, but I shall plunge forward with the most involved interpretation I see since pretty much all the others have trivial answers, hence why would one ask?

It looks to me as if you want to know, in essence, how many unique combinations of column 1 and column 2 occur. For instance, AA, AB, and AC seem to generate the three uses of "part # A" by programs. If there were another AB line, it would not add to that since the program B has been counted once already.

So, an approach that made pairs of the two cells on each line (AA, AB, and so on) and then took a set of the unique pair occurences in those pairs would eliminate the extra lines' data. Then one could fill column 3's cells with the desired sum by counting all the unique occurences for a given part, in my case by using a sum, and decide which cells to show nothing in by isolating either cell's data, column 1 for example, and checking to see if its contents occur above it (since if that's true, the result for that part # will have already been recorded).

Hence the following formula. Probably more elegant ways to do it, I grant, but it works...

```
=IFERROR(1/(1/SUM((LEFT(UNIQUE($A$2:$A$7&$B$2:$B$7),1)=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,$A$1:A1,1,FALSE)),A2,IF(VLOOKUP(A2,$A$1:A1,1,FALSE)=A2,0,A2)))*1)),"")
```

`UNIQUE($A$2:$A$7&$B$2:$B$7)` builds the pairs, then makes a list of the unique pairs. `LEFT()` gets column 1's contribution (they have to be paired to get the unique pairs, otherwise one would just start with column 1's data).

That is then compared to what exists in the cells above the row one is checking. The `$A$1:A1` range expands as one goes down the column, always being the range from the header cell to the cell just above the row you are checking. The lookup is performed to see if the cell's contents have occurred already. Three possiblities exist:  an error, true, and false. Due to the way errors are handled in Excel, that must be checked for first. One cannot use `IFERROR()` as one does not want the output of what is being looked up if it fails. If not an error, then it is tested again for TRUE or FALSE in  matching the cell's contents. If TRUE, it exists above that line and a "no output" result is desired. If FALSE, then like with the error possibility, one desires an output of the cell's contents.

The cell's contents are needed, if an output is desired, because they will be compared to the output of the `LEFT()` we started with. This will generate a TRUE or a FALSE which the `*1` at the end changes to 1's and 0's. So all the uniques pairs that start with that row's column 1 contents will generate 1's and the rest 0's. `SUM()` then adds these up for the count you desire.

But... if stopped here, you would have 0's where you clearly want blank cells. So `IFERROR()` can be used to give the result of the calculating from above, if it is the first occurrence in column 1 of that cell's contents, OR `""` if it is a second or later occurrence. This is done by realizing the calculation so far generates some non-zero value when one does not want a blank output and a 0 when one does want a blank. If one divides by the result, those 0's will give errors. Of course, 3 uses would then give 1/3 as the result which is no good, so wrap that in `()`'s and divide 1 by that. The errors will still happen so `IFERROR()` can still return the `""` but now those 1/3's and so on return to being integers.

So, a lot of gruntwork, but it does the trick. So far I have not been able to get it to use the SPILL functionality so the formula needs copied down the column from D2 to Dxxx.